# Prove that the median level of the dual of a set of non-degenerate points is formed by the duals of all points in the set.

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given a non-degenerate set of points, if we take the dual of each point and look at the median level of this line arrangement, how can one prove that the median level includes the duals of all the points at some point. Note that in this case, point (a, b) has the dual y=ax-b and the median level is a piece-wise linear function in the dual plane that has an equal number of lines above and below it at all times.

Comment: Your question is not clear ! How do you define for example the "median level of a line arrangement" ; what do you mean by "level" ? Is it the barycenter of all the points of the lines ? Please take an example.

Comment: Also, note that your question appears to be "If I form the median level from the set of all duals of the points in the set, how do I prove that it is formed from the set of all duals of the points in the set?" The answer is "by realizing that is exactly how you defined it".

Comment: I apologize for the delay in my response to your questions @JeanMarie

The median level is defined by a piece-wise linear function in the dual plane that has equal number of lines above and below it at all times.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have rephrased the question above to remove any confusion in what I am asking.

Comment: If you want to remove confusion, you cannot keep using an apparently very specialized jargon with no explanation. What does it mean for the median level to "include" a line "at some point"? What sort of degeneracy is the set of points to avoid? In certain contexts that would be clear, but quite frankly, your "points" appear to be simply reinterpreting the slopes and intercepts of lines as coodinates of a point. There does not appear to be any apparent connection to the geometry of the points here, only of the lines, which makes me wonder why this point iterpretation is needed.

Comment: After some consideration, I am guessing that you are defining "above" and "below" to mean "having higher/lower $y$ coordinate." But this is still not enough to define "the" median level. If the count of lines is even, any piecewise linear curve that only intersects the lines in a certain finite set of points would serve as a median level. Some clarification on exactly how this "median level" is defined is also going to be necessary.

Comment: I apologize once again for the jargon without context. I am using the language of Computational Geometry by BCKO, and my own interpretations of it. Perhaps mentioning their precise definitions would help.

Comment: BCKO defines a level as follows: the level of a point in an arrangement of lines is defined to be the number of lines strictly above it. So, if we consider this definition, I mean to say the set of all points with the median level, when I refer to the median level. 

So, to answer your question, you're right. If the number of lines are even, any piecewise linear curve would suffice. But it would still be a subset of the median level.

For simplicity, assuming that the number of lines is odd works.

Comment: I realize that I made my question a tad bit convoluted by introducing the duality into it. My question in essence is just trying to prove that in an arrangement of odd number of lines, the median level set, as defined above the set of all points that have exactly the same number of lines above and below it, will be a piecewise linear curve "made" of all the lines of the arrangement.

Comment: It is indeed much simpler like this ! A detail : I would transform "made of all lines" into "where each line contributes to a segment of the piecewise linear median"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an example of a MLL (Median Level Line) for a family of $n=5$ lines :

[image]

*The MLL is the red dotted broken line. Please note that on the left, the vertical order of the  5 lines : blue, brown, orange, purple, green, is inverted on the right. The MLL coincides with the median line (orange) at the beginning and at the end.*

Let us write the equations of lines $(L_k)$ under the form :

$$(L_k) : \ \ \ \ y=a_kt+b_k, \ \ k=1,2,\cdots n, \ \ \text{where} \ n=2m+1.$$

We have taken variable $t$ instead of $x$ because a **kinematics interpretation** will help. Consider $n=2m+1$ runners on a road. Let us interprete abscissa as time and ordinates as position. In this way, assuming that person n° $k$ runs at the uniform speed $a_k$, starting at position $b_k$ on the road, the set of lines can be interpreted as the time-space trajectories of these runners. We consider that the lines are in general position, therefore that all speeds $a_k$ are different ; WLOG, we can index the lines in such a way that, up to a time-shift, we have

$$a_1 > a_2 > \cdots > a_n \tag{1a}$$

and

$$b_1 < b_2 < \cdots < b_n \tag{1b}$$

(consider that the runners are given a "handicap" by letting them start from a position $b_k$ with a "remoteness" taking into account their speed $a_k$ as can be seen on the graphical representation).

Let $t_{p,q}$ the (unique) time instant where runners n° $p$ and $q$ ($p \ne q$) are situated simultaneously at the same point of the road. Let $t_{min}=\min{t_{p,q}}$ and $t_{max}=\max{t_{p,q}}$.

With our assumptions (1a) and (1b), we have $t_{min}>0$. We will take, in a symmetrical manner, an ending time $t_{end}>t_{max}$. Let us consider the median runner $R_m$ (which is, at starting time the one with median speed). For $t<t_{min}$ (and even some time later), it is this medial line $(L_m)$ which defines the MLL. At times $t>t_{end}$ (but hopefully before), there is again complete coincidence  between $(L_m)$ and the MLL (as can be seen on the graphic).

Meanwhile, what happens ? It is like in a relay race : runner n° $m$ gives its "baton" (stick) to the first runner he meets (either "hit" by him or being "hitted" from the rear) ; on its turn, the new holder of the baton will give it to the runner he will meet next, and so on... until the baton comes finally back into the hands of the initial holder n° $m$...

This establishes the existence of this red line in this context (an existence that can be obtained of course by different means).

Now, the final touch. Why are all other lines $(L_k), \ k \ne m$ sharing at least a common segment with median line MLL ? Because this line divides the plane into an upper $U$ region and a lower $L$ region and that all these lines have one of their endpoints (for $t=t_{min}$ and $t=t_{max}$) in $L$ and the other in $U$. This is a topological explanation.

But we can say it with our kinematic framework.

Any runner n° $p$ that runs faster than the runner n° $m$ (which means that $p>m$), although having started earlier will progressively reach a certain number of the runners. Assuming that it never reaches the baton-holder, it would mean that, at the end, he stays behind runner n° $m$ : contradiction. Same reasoning for a runner who is running slower than runner n° $m$.

Remark : we can assume all the slopes are $\ge 0$. If this is not the case, we can replace all of them by $y=(a_k-a_{min})x+b_k$ where $a_{min}$ is the smallest slope. This linear operation preserves the median line in the sense that one retrieves the original median line by doing the inverse operation.

Remark : Interesting things can be found into [this document](https://ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/lehre/CG12/lecture/Chapter%2013.pdf)..

Comment: I have used this kind of kinematic diagrams in different answers on SE Math, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2151872/305862) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4341309/305862).

Comment: Any comment ?... I  haven't studied to "what" an MLL is associated with in the duality $y=ax+b \leftrightarrow (a,b)$, and the possible interest of using this duality for getting it.